# How to upgrade PHP with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, freebsd

I tried to upgrade PHP from 5.2.12 to 5.2.14 (FreeBSD 7) (by make install), but after installation 'php -v' in command line shows '5.2.14' and phpinfo() shows '5.2.12'. How can it be?

Now I'm trying to install PHP patched with PHP-FPM, but get an error that says 'make deinstall' before.

How can I properly install PHP now? And what happens if I execute 'make deinstall'? Will config file, extensions and some settings be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

In order to upgrade any port you must run `make deinstall` :)
Whole procedure should look something like this: `make clean && make build && make deinstall && make reinstall` or simply use portupgrade:
`portupgrade -fR -o lang/php52`

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your http server?  It could still be using an in-memory instance of the old PHP 5.2.12 library.

Comment: Yes, I restarted Nginx and PHP-FPM. But main problem now is in other thing. I installed PHP 5.2.14 without PHP-FPM patch and if this version of PHP will run, PHP-FPM will not work. And at the same time I cannot reinstall PHP without deinstall it. What must I do?

Comment: Sorry I have not use FPM so I cannot speak from experience.